# Playing two sounds Simutaneosly

Tags: android, audio, media-player, soundpool, android-audiomanager

I am trying to play two sounds simutaneosly in android.I have created two MediaPlayers and am using the code below.They are currently playing one after another.Or not exactly one after another but kinda delayed into eachother.

```
private void playSound(){
       if (mp1 != null) {
           mp1.release(); 
        }
       if (mp2 != null) {
            mp2.release(); 
         }


        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundArray[0]); 
        mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundArray[3]);
        mp1.start();
        mp2.start();

      }
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you mean "delayed", is that seconds, microseconds, ten seconds? How close after each other do you want them to be played, *exactly* at the same time, and not a moment sooner?

Comment: Very short... microseconds.I want them to be played at exactly the same time yes.

Comment: I meant when they played they were delayed a little into eachother.I just want them both play play at the Exact same time.

Comment: I'm in a dire need of achieving the same thing. Wondering how did the mixing go. Any chance of solution?

Answer (score 5):

Playing two digital sounds simultaneously is as simple as summing them together (as in the real world), so you could do that yourself while filling the buffer (and have control over timing).

This could cause the amplitude to raise, so care should be taken to not surpass the numeric bounds of the array type if you don't want to cause clipping artifacts.

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376036/algorithm-to-mix-sound) might also be helpful

Comment: Thanks, but seems to advanced for my current knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

Doing two things at *exactly* the same time is ..difficult. In a one threaded environment the OS needs to jump between threads to simulate them running at the same time. So to be able to run them at the "same time", you need to start two threads and wait for them to arrive at the point where they should be synchronized and then let both threads now that they should continue.

Another solution would be to merge the two sound streams so that it sounds like if it's two sounds playing when it's actually one. Altough I'm not that proficient in sound manipulation, and definitely not on Android...

A solution for the first would be to spawn two threads, start them both and then use a `wait()` and `notify()` to get them to call `MediaPlayer.start()` at the same time, possibly with the [Lock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) class.

---

Okay, so a long example of how to synchronize two threads (based on example [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) are:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

class SynchronizeTest implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        final Condition cond = lock.newCondition(); 

        new Thread(new SynchronizeTest(1, lock, cond)).start();
        new Thread(new SynchronizeTest(2, lock, cond)).start();
    }

    private final int number;
    private final ReentrantLock lock;
    private final Condition cond;

    public SynchronizeTest(int number, ReentrantLock lock, Condition cond) {
        this.number = number;
        this.lock = lock;
        this.cond = cond;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            if (number == 1) {
                put();
            }
            else {
                take();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) { }
    }

    public void put() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            cond.await();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        System.out.println(number);
    }

    public void take() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        // wait for put to take the lock
        Thread.sleep(300);
        try {
            cond.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        System.out.println(number);
    } 
}
```

This can probably be coded much simpler, but I haven't done that much Java coding lately.. :-(

Comment: If it's not too much trouble or won't take too long.Would you happen to have some demo code.If not that is o.k. I found that using midi is sufficient for my needs.

Comment: @james: Unfortunately no. I can try to whip up a small Java example (it won't be pretty) but I don't have any android phone to test it on at the moment.

Comment: @james: Provided a (long) example. It's alot of code only to synchronize two threads, but I warned you that it wouldn't be pretty. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify the following to get this to work.It should be noted that it did not work in the emulator(they still played one after another), but after putting it on the phone it worked great.

http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html

Comment: sorry for the questions but i want to make sure i'm following your solution.  so in the end you just called;

playSound(1);
playSound(2);
playSound(3);
playSound(4);

i have personally found that this still didnt work for me.  If you did something other than this can you explain? thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get two sounds Playing At the exact same time by using the SoundPool class.

Comment: if you are calling them in succession... then they are really not being started at the same time, there will be very small delay.  It will allow the sounds to overlap but the timing what is important here.

Comment: if you found a solution can you update your post or answer your own question?

Answer (score -1):

Organize your code:
Create the objects and load the samples first. Then use one method to play them, and another to pause/release them.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer snd1, snd2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    snd1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.s01);
    snd2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.s02);
}

public void playSounds(View v) {
    snd1.start();
    snd2.start();
}
public void stopSounds(View v) {
    snd1.pause();
    snd2.pause();
}
```

}