# Playing two sounds simultaneously, one of these sent over Bluetooth - iOS and Android

Tags: iphone, android, streaming, audio, bluetooth

This question is relevant for both Android and iOS developers:

Is it possible to play two sounds (files/streams) simultaneously in an application, where one of those is played through the speakers of the phone, whilst the other is streamed via Bluetooth to an external headset (or other bluetooth capable device)?

Comment: [A similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350212/playing-two-sounds-simutaneosly) was started just a few days ago on the Android side of this topic. Hope it helps.

Comment: well, I've went over this thread, that's how I understood you can have two streams simultaneously, but my question is kind of "the next level" to this one. I'll try to add it there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On stock OS iOS devices (iPhone, et.al.), an app is only given one (stereo or mono) audio output route.