# Android:sound pool and service

Tags: android, android-service

I have create the service which implement the media player class to play the back ground music.But now i want to convert into sound pool so that multiple sound can be played.
 can help any on which can provide me the some link of source code?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just i have implemented the service with background sound,i have check the code from http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/11/play-audio-resources-using-soundpool.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    // Random number generator
    private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundsMap;
    int SOUND1=1;
    int SOUND2=2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

        soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
        soundsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        soundsMap.put(SOUND1, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.baby_laugh, 1));
        soundsMap.put(SOUND2, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.touchdown, 1));
    }
    public void playSound(int sound, float fSpeed) {
        AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float streamVolumeCurrent = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float streamVolumeMax = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;


        soundPool.play(soundsMap.get(sound), volume, volume, 1, 0, fSpeed);
       }


    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /** method for clients */
    public int getRandomNumber() {
      return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }

    public void soundPlay(int index){

         playSound(index, 1.0f);
         Log.d("SOUND1","hi1");

    }   }
```

you call from Activity using

```
public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    LocalService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.a_button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service

      if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    /** Called when a button is clicked (the button in the layout file attaches to
      * this method with the android:onClick attribute) */
    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        if (mBound) {
            // Call a method from the LocalService.
            // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
            // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
            int num = mService.getRandomNumber();
            Toast.makeText(this, "number: " + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {


        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }


        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (mBound) {
            // Call a method from the LocalService.
            // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
            // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
               mService.soundPlay(1);
            int num = mService.getRandomNumber();
            Toast.makeText(this, "number: " + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you to all who help me.specially to who write the blog.