# MediaPlayer gives error(-38,0) when playing audio repeats by clicking play button

Tags: android, media-player

MediaPlayer gives error(-38,0) when playing audio repeats by clicking play button.
I am trying to make an app like musical pad first time it plays OK but when you click multiple times it goes in hang mode and shows error.

Comment: can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the media player buffer is getting full .
Use [`SoundPool`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) instead

```
 int SoundArr[] = { R.raw.birds_whistling, R.raw.come_bye,
            R.raw.cute_whistle, R.raw.kill_bill_whistle, R.raw.look_back,
             };

SoundPool mSoundPool;
HashMap<Integer,Integer> mSoundPoolMap;
AudioManager  mAudioManager;

 mSoundPool=(SoundPool) SoundImageAdaptor.mSoundPool;
 mSoundPoolMap =SoundImageAdaptor.mSoundPoolMap;//i'm using a grid view adaptor
 mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
/* code to that ensures the sound plays even when media player buffer gets full*/
                 if(!(mSoundPoolMap.containsKey(position)))
                 addSound(position, SoundArr[position]);
                 playSound(position);
```

You can check this link also [How to properly use SoundPool on a game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437505/how-to-properly-use-soundpool-on-a-game)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just prepare the mediaplayer with the same source once more when clicked again. You need to either release the old data

```
mMediaPlayer.release();
```

or if it is the same audio better just use

```
mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0)
```

to jump to the beginning again, no need for another prepare round.

Soundpoool is great for small files yet cant handle bigger audio files.

**UPDATE:**

Actually just got the same error in one of my apps: So my mistake was

```
mMediaPlayer.stop();
mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
```

which is not correct as after stop you have to prepare again. The correct way is

```
mMediaPlayer.pause();
mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
```

The official docu as usual is very good

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html