# Android: lag using SoundPool

Tags: android, audio

According to [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) and previously asked questions, `SoundPool` seems to be the best option to play a sound without too much latency.

I am testing this class and currently have the following code:

```
mSoundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
soundID = mSoundPool.load(getActivity(), R.raw.son_1, 1);
```

I'm playing the sound inside a thread as follow:

```
// Play sound
System.out.println("TIC");
mSoundPool.play(soundID, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, 1f);

System.out.println("TAC");
var += 1;
mTextView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mTextView.setText(String.format("%d", var));
    }
});

System.out.println("TOC");
```

Calling the previous code in a loop yields the following Logcat:

```
04-18 20:08:52.455: I/System.out(955): TIC
04-18 20:08:52.456: I/System.out(955): TAC
04-18 20:08:52.460: I/System.out(955): TOC
04-18 20:08:53.457: I/System.out(955): TIC
04-18 20:08:53.457: I/System.out(955): TAC
04-18 20:08:53.458: I/System.out(955): TOC
```

So everything is called pretty much at the same time. However, the sound always plays with a delay after `mTextView` is updated. The delay is small but audible.

How should I proceed to lower as much as possible this delay? How does one achieve to play a sound and display something simultaneously in a game, or in a metronome for example?

I did try the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437505/how-to-properly-use-soundpool-on-a-game), but it didn't help.