# How do I implement AUDIO_SERVICE in widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-audiomanager

I am implementing audio manager widget application. I would like to use the following code.

```
this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)
```

but I can not use because I extend AppWidgetProvider class(not Activity class).

How should I change my coding? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the public methods that you can override in [AppWidgetProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#) will receive a Context that the provider is running within.
Through that context you should be able to get the system service:

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer but in my case thee following link helped me:[Sound pool and Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580537/androidsound-pool-and-service)