# How to play multiple sound at the same time?

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

I want to make an android program to play several sounds from the raw folder.And each sound can be controlled by its own play/pause button and the other thing is, this program can run in background also(as a service) How do i do that please some one help me to do this I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580537/androidsound-pool-and-service) but it is not working.Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Create multiple media player object and put data source different so that you can play multiple sounds.

Comment: @RushabhPatel I tried multiples MediaPlayer and they does not perform at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to use `SoundPool` class to manage multiple sounds at the same time.