# Playing game sounds

Tags: android

I need to play sound effects in my game such as jump, failed, shot etc.
So for this purpose I have selected SoundPool class. But there were some times when it lagged.
So I wonder what is correct way to use this class. I have tried to use play method in new thread, it seems work better but I don't know if I am correct. 
Please advice how to use object of this class correctly for better performance.

Comment: It might help if you post examples of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to implement Sound / Music into your game is by using Service component. Read this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5590401/2783104) for an example.