# How to use custom calendar view in Android and how to set alert for reminder?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I need to make an Android application to show a Calendar control. I have tried to find such a control in the default widgets provided by Android, but could not find it. How to integrate a Calendar control in an Android application?

I also want the Calendar to enable adding events and reminders to specific dates.

Comment: Need to create reminder application in android????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lags while playing 2 sounds on the same time in timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012933/lags-while-playing-2-sounds-on-the-same-time-in-timer/12130048#12130048)

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

This may help you.

**UPDATE:**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

http://blog.blundellapps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

http://android.arnodenhond.com/tutorials/alarm-notification

May be this is what he is looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Use android `TimerTask` in app.

[Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

If something else is what you're looking for, try to make your question clearer.

Here is how you can use it:
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012933/lags-while-playing-2-sounds-on-the-same-time-in-timer/12130048#12130048)

**UPDATE**

I believe this is what you're looking for:
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976098/how-to-set-reminder-in-android/5976386#5976386)

Comment: i need  to create one sample application for viewing the calender