# Custom calendar view to add indicators

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use custom calendar view in Android and how to set alert for reminder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142737/how-to-use-custom-calendar-view-in-android-and-how-to-set-alert-for-reminder)

I want to add a notification like icon inside a day in the calendar view of android, is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Go through the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142737/how-to-use-custom-calendar-view-in-android-and-how-to-set-alert-for-reminder